# Every face of compact convex set is closed?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Well, this is my doubt:

> Let $\vec{E}$ be a n.v.s. and $K\subset \vec{E}$ a compact convex set. Then every face of $K$ is closed.

Any hint in order to prove it is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The intersection of two closed sets is closed.

Comment: In your opinion... what is a face?

Comment: @AndréCaldas A face $F$ of $K$ is a set such that , if $x,y\in A$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$ are such that $\theta x+(1-\theta)y\in F$, then $x,y \in F$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for your answer, but how can I use that fact here?

Comment: @JuanPablo : The compact convex set is itself a closed set, and if you take "face" to mean an $(n-1)$-dimensional boundary, then a face is the intersection of the compact convex subset with an $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane, which is itself a closed set.  So the face is an intersection of two closed sets.  And a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Is here any way of linking my definition of face with yours?. Or how can I prove that these definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Let $P$ be the affine span of $F$, i.e., the space of all affine combinations of elements of $F$. Begin by showing that $P\cap K \subseteq F$... By the way, do you assume that $\vec E$ is finite dimensional? This is what @MichaelHardy implicitly assumed in his comment, so it would help to clarify this point.

Comment: @user100000 nope, the space is not assumed to be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you problem is stated, it is not true in general. Let $E=\mathbb{R}^2$, and $K=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|\leq 1\right\}$, which is compact and convex.

Let $F$ be the ''upper semicircle'', that is $F=\left\{x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|=1\text{ and }x_2>0\right\}$. Then $F$ is clearly a face, that is, it satisfies the following (as in the comments): ''if $x,y\in K$ and $0<\theta<1$ are such that $\theta x+(1-\theta)y\in F$, then both $x,y\in F$.'' But $F$ is not closed.

One question you could ask is "Are maximal faces of $K$ closed"? (that is, faces which are not properly contained in any other face). In the example I gave, the only maximal face if $\mathbb{S}^1$, which is closed.

Comment: Nice! I had thought of an infinite dimensional example (probability Borel measures in a locally compact space)... but yours is much simpler!

Comment: -1: While this answers the question as stated by OP in the comments, and while there is the disclaimer "the way your problem is stated", this question is the top result when one searches for compactness of a face in a compact convex set. As the usual definition of face includes "convex", which the OP omitted, this answer becomes misleading and doesn't actually answer the queston in the title.

Answer (score 2):

You missed an important part in the definition of a face and that is that every face is a **convex** set. This means that the "upper semicircle" cannot be a face in the unit circle. Only faces in this case are $0$ dimensional, i.e. points of the boundary. (so called extreme points)