# Prove that faces of a closed bounded convex set are also closed

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

Let $S$ be a closed bounded convex subset of a Banach space $E$.

> **Definition :** A convex subset $F\subseteq S$ is called a face of $S$ if $\forall x\in F,y\in S,z\in S$ such that $x\in]y,z[$ we have $y$ and $z$ in $F$.

I am wondering if this implies that $F$ is closed.

The only approach that I tried that didn't fail (but that I couldn't see through) is the following. For any $x\in S\setminus F$ there exist a continuous linear functional $f_x$ (I can't prove that, it feels like this would use the Hahn Banach theorem and needs $F$ to be closed in the first place) and some $c_x$ such that $f_x(x) < c_x \leq f_x(y)$ for all $y\in F$. I think it is doable to show that $F=\bigcap_{x\in S\setminus F} \{ y: f_x(y)\geq c_x \}$ which would make it closed. I don't think this approach is very promissing but I added it in case it can bring some intuition.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529269/42969.

Comment: @MartinR It is the same question, except that the answer is deceptive since it uses a flaw in the formulation of the question (that I also had actually) to find a counter example.

Comment: This is proved for closed convex sets in Corollary 18.1.1 of Convex Analysis, R.T. Rockafellar, 1996.

Answer (score 1):

Following Corollary 18.1.1 of Convex Analysis, R.T. Rockafellar, 1996 under @daw 's advice here is a proof.

Let $\mathrm{ri}(C)=\{ x\in C:\mathrm{cone}(C-x)=\mathrm{span}(C-x)\}$.

If $F=\emptyset$, it is closed, so assume that $F\neq \emptyset$ and in particular $\emptyset\neq\mathrm{ri}(F)\subseteq F\cap\mathrm{ri}(\overline F)$. We show that $F=\overline F$. Let $x\in F\cap\mathrm{ri}(\overline F)$ then for any $y\in \overline{F}\setminus\{ x \}$, there exist $z\in\overline F$ such that $x\in]y,z[$ (otherwise we would have $\overline F\cap \{ \lambda x+(1-\lambda)y:\lambda\geq 0 \}=[x,y]$ and so $x\notin\mathrm{ri}(\overline F)$) and so $y\in F$. So that $\overline F=F$.

This proof seems correct to me but any improvement or comment is welcome.